# How can I replace text and change encoding from a shell script without Vim?

Tags: text-processing, vim

I have a line of shell script that looks like this:

```
vim file.xml -c "s/\r/\r/g" -c "set fileencoding=utf8" -c "wq"
```

It works perfectly from the (macOS) terminal, but when I execute it within another program (FileMaker running AppleScript), it hangs. I think it's because Vim is actually launching (I see it flash in the terminal) and either FileMaker or AppleScript fail on that.

How can I do the same thing as the above, but only with command line tools that don't launch an app with an interface?

Comment: you might use sed instead of vim, check regexp to adapt it.

Answer (score 1):

`ex` is Vim, for scripting.

It will take the same commands as Vim does but it can run without a terminal (tty). You can pass it a `-s` flag for "silent".

See [`:help -s-ex`](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#-s-ex):

> `-s`: Silent or batch mode. [...] To be used when Vim is used to execute Ex commands from a file **instead of a terminal**. [...]

(Beware that `-s` will suppress diagnostics and error messages and it might have additional side effects. See the full help for details. It's possible you don't need it in your case, but it's likely you might.)

You can run your command as:

```
ex -s file.xml -c "s/\r/\r/g" -c "set fileencoding=utf8" -c "wq"
```

Note that "ex-mode" is also available with the `-e` flag, so this should also work:

```
vim -e -s file.xml -c "s/\r/\r/g" -c "set fileencoding=utf8" -c "wq"
```

Comment: Nope. vi is the visual (full-screen) mode of the (line) editor ex, which is an evolution of the original Unix line editor ed, in turn, ed begat grep and sed (stream editor, ed for scripting/editing data "streaming by").

Comment: @vonbrand Yes fair enough. "Ex is Vim, for scripting" was tongue-in-cheek for "Sed is Vim, for scripting."

Answer (score 0):

`sed` is vim, but for scripting. It can be used to stream data through it, or to process one or more files. It was based on the same code as vi and ed. It is non-interactive, so does not have a window.

Incidentally I did not think that `vim` had its own window. May be something (a wrapper) is launching it in a window.

Comment: Is there a way to take care of the file encoding with `sed`? `git` doesn't like UTF-16, apparently (treats it as a binary file), which is the reason for the saving it as UTF-8. Some quick searching doesn't show anything to change the file encoding with `sed` like I am with `vim`.

Comment: The is a utf converter (I Can't remember the name), we use pipes to join it to other tools. No one likes utf-16 (except microsoft and javascript). It is a terrible encoding. unicode is at least 24 bit, so you get extension pages in utf-16, Common characters are 16-bit, but most are 32-bit. A lot of software does not realise this, and breaks.

Comment: @Chuck You're looking for `iconv`.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is with `git`, you can configure (details in `gitattributes(5)`, typically in a `.gitattibutes` file in the root of the repository) the `working-tree-encoding` to use UTF16 for (selected) checked-out files, translating to/from UTF8 on checkin/checkout. Internally `git` uses UTF8 (for e.g. `diff`, searches, show stuff, ...).

Be careful: Non-native git might not understand this, and give grief.